How to SUM quantity of the same products in SQL?
Sorry for my English at first.
I'm learning SQL in W3schools's SQL Tryit Editor. You may find there the same tables on which I operate.
How can I sum quantity of the same products?
I tried this:
SELECT Products.ProductName, OrderDetails.Quantity, Customers.Country
FROM Orders
JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID WHERE Customers.Country = 'Germany';

and it was my result:
SQL code and result
As you can see for example there is two rows with "Boston Crab Meat" and quantity of this didn't sum.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_sum.asp

Well it would help to start with SUM, but you'll likely want to use GROUP BY eventually to group items together into the sum.

Thx for your comments! I tried this yesterday but I couldn't connect the dots and today it works. Thank you!

SOLUTION:
SELECT Products.ProductName, SUM(OrderDetails.Quantity) AS Quantity, Customers.Country
FROM Orders
JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID WHERE Customers.Country = 'Germany'
GROUP BY ProductName;

